# Create setup file with SQL Server 2008 via installshield 2010

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, setup-project, setup-deployment, installshield-2010

I want to create a setup file with Installshield 2010.

I have written my program with wpf and SQL Server 2008.

I created the file but during the installation, it starts to install SQL Server 2008 with all details.

I want to know can I do this? I don't install SQL Server 2008 or connect to database via any way such as MSDE for SQL Server 2000.

If I have to install SQL Server Express, can I install it as the user have no problem and the installation do automatically with no user interference?

Answer (score 1):

You can start by reading more about prerequisites and how they are configured:
http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield16helplib_sp1/IncludingRedistributables.htm

With the prerequisite editor you can specify the application you want to run (SQL Server installer):
http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield16helplib_sp1/SetupPrereqEditor.htm

and its command line:
http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield16helplib_sp1/UIRefPrereqEditor_AppRun.htm

To install SQL Server prerequisites silently, you can use the SQL Server installer command line options in your prerequisite command line:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(SQL.100).aspx